# Getting a PHP PDO error, How can this be solved

Tags: php, pdo

I am getting the below error, any idea what could be the issue here:

```
public function connect()
{
    $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=suggestotron", "root", null);
}


public function getAllTopics()
{
    $query = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM topics");
    $query->execute();

    return $query;
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Notice: Undefined property: PDOStatement::$execute in /var/www/suggestotron/public/TopicData.php on line 19
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: It's might be $this->connection is not working. did you extend your db connection class here properly.?

Comment: Are you sure that's where the error is? O_o I'd normally expect that if you were doing `$query->execute;`. Is $this->connection a simple PDO object?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh yes, I think so, re edited the above code to include the connection part

Comment: @JonStirling yes it is , re edited the above code with the connection part.

Comment: As mentioned in a previous comment, this code as posted could not cause an `undefined property PDOStatement::$execute` error. The statement was correctly prepared because it _is_ a `PDOStatement` object, but it seems that somewhere else you have omitted the `()` from an `execute()` call.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski This is a point! Exactly what I would say. Actually, somewhere in the code there is something like this: $somePdoStatement->execute;

Comment: Again it seems right code. i think you have somewhere else did any mistake related to executed that pointed by other people int his conversation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone, It was a stupid error, instead of $query->execute(); I had typed $query->execute; Have a great weekend